# Foreign key and cascade problems on delete Symfony4/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, cascade

I want to delete a property with my user but I have the following error :

An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM property WHERE id = ?' with params [1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gestImmo`.`equipment`, CONSTRAINT `FK_D338D583517FE9FE` FOREIGN KEY (`equipment_id`) REFERENCES `property` (`id`))

I googled it and (I think) it's a cascade problem. So I searched on forums but I didn't solved the problem. I asked for help to an experimented coworker but we didn't fix the mistake ... Hope you could help me.

In my User entity there is :

```
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Property", mappedBy="userProperty")
     */
    private $properties;
```

In my property Entity there is :

```
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="properties")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $userProperty;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Equipment", mappedBy="equipment")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="equipement_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $equipments;
```

and in my equipments entity there is :

```
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Property", inversedBy="equipments")
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $equipment;
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete property because it is referenced in column `equipment_id` in table `equipment`. This foreign key constraint means that `equipment.equipment_id` must point to a valid(existing) id of property - `property.id`.
If you want to delete property, then before that you either:

- Delete `equipment` records where `equipment_id` = {id of property you want to delete}
- Or change those `equipment_id` to null

**EDIT**

Looks like your annotations are incorrect. If I understood your relations correctly, then it should be something like this.

`Property` entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="properties")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_property_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $userProperty;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Equipment", mappedBy="equipment")
     */
    private $equipments;
```

`Equipment` entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Property", inversedBy="equipments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="equipment_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $equipment;
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `onDelete="CASCADE"` in your manyToOne annotation should be enough.

Don't forget to `bin/console make:migration` after that. Everything you change in your *ORM* must be migrated in order to apply the changes into the database.